# Unresolved reference: add and RemoveAt Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Que tal tengo el siguiente codigo para agregar fotografias desde mi galeria pero al convertirlo de java a kotlin la funcion .add me la pasa a subrayar en rojo y con la leyenda `Unresolved reference: add`, de igual manera en mi clase adapter estoy utilizando `list.remove` pero al convertir a kotlin cambio el `.remove` por `.removeAt` y lo marco en rojo me podrian orientar para saber de que manera lo soluciono

Java funcion `.add`

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode !=RESULT_CANCELED){

            switch (requestCode){
                case 1:
                    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data !=null){

                        int count = data.getClipData().getItemCount();
                        for(int i=0; i<count; i++){
                            Uri image = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                            String imagePath = FileUtils.getPath(MultiUpload.this,image);
                            images.add(Uri.parse(imagePath));
                        }

                        ImageListAdapter adapter = new ImageListAdapter(MultiUpload.this,images);
                        gvImagenes.setAdapter(adapter);
                    }
            }

        }
    }
```

Y asi se ve una ves lo converti a Kotlin

```
    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
            when (requestCode) {
                1 -> if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    val count = data.clipData!!.itemCount
                    var i = 0
                    while (i < count) {
                        val image = data.clipData!!.getItemAt(i).uri
                        val imagePath = FileUtils.getPath(this@MainActivity, image)
                        images.add(Uri.parse(imagePath))
                        i++
                    }
                    val adapter = ImageListAdapter(this@MainActivity, images)
                    gvImagenes!!.adapter = adapter
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Java funcion `.remove`

```
    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if(view == null) {
            layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_gv_imagenes, null);
        }

        ImageView ivImagen = view.findViewById(R.id.ivImagen);
        ImageButton ibtnEliminar = view.findViewById(R.id.ibtnEliminar);

        ivImagen.setImageURI(listaImagenes.get(i));

        ibtnEliminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                listaImagenes.remove(i);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
```

Kotlin `removeAt`

```
    override fun getView(position: Int, view: View, parent: ViewGroup?): View? {

        var view = view

        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_image, null)

        var imageView = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.image)
        var ibtnEliminar = view.findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.ibtnEliminar)


        val file = File(list!![position].path)

        Picasso.get().load(file).into(imageView)
        imageView.setImageURI(list!![position])

        ibtnEliminar.setOnClickListener {
            list!!.removeAt(position)
            notifyDataSetChanged()
        }

        return view
    }
```